# How to use foursquare public search api in a wordpress plugin to avoid exposing our key/secret

Tags: wordpress, foursquare

I'm adding location to my wordpress plugin and wanted to use the [foursquare public API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search). What i wanted to understand is how exactly that would work since my plugin will be installed on various system. As you can see the user doesn't need to be authenticated, so i could provide in the plugin our own client_id an client_secret to make calls to the api, but that would expose them to the public and some competitor could abuse that to break the rate limit. What's the best way to handle this?How does instagram work for example?I can use location search even if i'm not logged into foursquare, how do they do this? My idea was to proxy the call to our api and make the call from our api by adding our client_id/secret and have the user optionally insert his own, but is it really a bad idea hardcoding the id/secretin the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way; each user of your plugin should get foursquare API credentials separately and fill it in the settings of the plugin (dashboard) to activate it.

Comment: Yes but i'd want to avoid that, that means that the user must register on foursquare which is something i wouldn't want to do. I could also use google maps then.I have alredy implemented the possibility for the user to add it's own credetinals, but i want things to work even if he doesn't.

Comment: Unless you want to associate all calls with your single app (which is probably not the best thing to do here), I think @Ferhad has the right idea. Each user of your plugin (nb: not the eventual end-consumer of the plugin, but the WordPress blog owner) should supply you with their Foursquare credentials (e.g., client id and secret). There's not really a good way around this OAuth issue; take a look at how some other plugins handle it: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-to-twitter/installation/ http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-instagram/installation/